# .sty file in preamble

Tags: packages, preamble

Suppose I have the following code:

```
%! xelatex

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra,xgreek}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{definitions}
%\newtheorem{prop}{Πρόταση}
\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
Μπλα μπλα μπλα
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

`definitions` is a `.sty` file where it contains only the command `\newtheorem{prop}{Πρόταση}`. Now, if I run the code as it is, the output will be just `Μπλα μπλα μπλα.`  However, if I comment the  `\usepackage{definitions}` command and un-comment the `\newtheorem{prop}{Πρόταση}`, the output is going to be as expected. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you read the console output? Don't you get complaints about the file?

Comment: Purely a guess, but maybe you have the wrong text encoding in the .sty file?

Comment: Actually, first error is from Babel.  This doesn't compile for me at all.

Comment: `"Environment prop undefined. \begin{prop}"` is what the console spits out.

Comment: @cfr I use `xelatex`.

Comment: I'm using XeLaTeX, too, You need to load `babel` and not `greek`. `greek` should be passed as an option.

Comment: @cfr Sorry, I forgot a character. It should be `xgreek` instead of `greek`. I just edited it.

Comment: @jon I agree. However, `xgreek` does work fine in my testing. And TNR seems to be fine. (But that's going to depend on the version installed on the system, of course.) Even works fine with no Babel, `xgreek` and `xltxtra` and TNR.

Comment: @jon Minimally. Perhaps you could provide an answer saying more here? I really answered because it seemed to be a Babel error. I know nothing about `xgreek`. (I do know not to use `xltxtra` but not really why. Only that the best bits are not got without it.)

Comment: @cfr -- My understanding (vague and hazy as it is since I stick to LuaTeX in the hope that I one day learn enough Lua for that to be useful) is that `xltxtra` nowadays is reduced to offering you ways to typeset (variants of) XeTeX, super- and subscripts, and so-called vulgar fractions. I believe the scope of `xltxtra` used to be greater (not sure, however).

Comment: @cfr -- Actually, I'm going to delete all my comments but the penultimate one. I can't reproduce the problem either. (No need for me to add an aswer, either. I already +1-ed yours....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine if you pay attention to the errors and follow Babel's advice:

```
\begin{filecontents}{definitions.sty}
  \newtheorem{prop}{Πρόταση}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[greek]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{definitions}
\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
Μπλα μπλα μπλα
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

[image: proper output]

However, your package should also declare itself properly. Minimally something like:

```
\ProvidesPackage{definitions}
...
\endinput
```

**EDIT** Your corrected MWE compiles without error on my system, producing the same output as shown above. While the packages may not be recommended, they do not seem to lead to compilation errors:

```
\begin{filecontents}{definitions.sty}
  \newtheorem{prop}{Πρόταση}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra,xgreek}% Not recommended: certainly drop xltxtra; consider using babel or polyglossia
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{definitions}
\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
Μπλα μπλα μπλα
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While I run it instead of `Πρόταση 1 Mπλα μπλα μπλα`, the output is `?????? 1 Μπλα μπλα μπλα`.  How should I modify the .sty file? I used your initial code.

Comment: @thanasissdr That works for me. I can't tell you how to fix it because I can't reproduce the issue. The code I posted produces the output I posted. (Either lot of code.) Check the encoding on the `.sty` file as jon suggested. And read the console output carefully. Maybe your bold TNR doesn't know Greek?

Comment: I don't know how I can check that. However, I'm going to upvote your answer for your suggestion to use either `babel` or `polyglossia` rather than `xgreek`. Thank you.

Comment: @thanasissdr You can use `otfinfo -s <path to font>` to see which scripts are supported.

Comment: Οκ, I finally managed it! Again, thank you.

Comment: @thanasissdr Excellent - good to hear!